# Use DateTimePicker to only allow certain hours of the day to be enabled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Desired behavior is something like an appointment app. If someone booked an appointment at 10:00, mark hour 10 disabled in DateTimePicker. If no one booked an appointment at that time, make the hour slot selectable and enabled. Is this possible with the .NET DateTimePicker control?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set a [MinValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate?view=netframework-4.7) and a [MaxValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate?view=netframework-4.7) for the [System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker?view=netframework-4.7) but it is not possible to choose blocks of dates that are not allowed. This is something you would have to add yourself. There are 2 possible methods of doing this:

- Handling the [ValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged?view=netframework-4.7) event, then validate the time chosen.
- Inherit the DateTimePicker class and add the extra functionality in there.